# List 'target' of 'links'

Tags: powershell, shortcut

I need to get the 'target' inside of a shortcut link to another server.
But… when I use `-Recurse`, it follows the links, instead of simply just getting the shortcut target.

Here is code that I found online that I edited to serve my purpose. But it goes into the links and tries to find shortcuts within another server:

```
#Created By Scott

$varLogFile = "E:\Server\GetBriefsTargets.log"
$varCSVFile = "E:\Server\GetBriefsTargets.csv"

function Get-StartMenuShortcuts
{
    $Shortcuts = Get-ChildItem -Recurse "F:\Connect" -Include *.lnk
    #$Shortcuts = Get-ChildItem -Recurse "D:\Scripts\scott_testing" -Include *.lnk
    $Shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    foreach ($Shortcut in $Shortcuts)
    {
        $Properties = @{
            ShortcutName = $Shortcut.Name;
            ShortcutFull = $Shortcut.FullName;
            ShortcutPath = $shortcut.DirectoryName
            Target = $Shell.CreateShortcut($Shortcut).targetpath
        }
        New-Object PSObject -Property $Properties
    }

    [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Shell) | Out-Null
}

$Output = Get-StartMenuShortcuts
$Output
ECHO "$Output" >> $varLogFile
ECHO "$Output" >> $varCSVFile
```

Could someone please offer advice on what I can change so that it still finds all of the shortcut links in all of the folders? and stops going inside of those links?

ie:

F:\Connect\CLIENTA\shortcut.lnk
F:\Connect\CLIENTB\shortcut.lnk
etc.

There's about 100 clients that I have to get their links and I don't want to do it manually (each month).

Here is the error that I get upon trying to run this script:

```
Get-ChildItem : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully
qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must
be less than 248 characters.
At D:\Scripts\scott_testing\GetShortcutTarget_edit1.ps1:8 char:18
+     $Shortcuts = Get-ChildItem -Recurse "F:\Connect" -Include *.lnk
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (F:\Connect\CLIENTA\briefs\FILENAME:String) [Get-ChildItem], PathTooLongException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

It is going 'inside' of the link and trying to find shortcuts on another server.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just finding a local directory inside "connect" that has a path of 248+ characters. `get-childitem` doesn't go inside links on a recursive search by itself when I run it.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` doesn't follow shortcuts. What are you talking about?

Comment: The script goes to: F:\Connect\CLIENTA\briefs.lnk  <-- it then goes inside of the path of briefs.lnk to something like \\IPADDRESS\CLIENTDATA\CLIENTA\FOLDERA\filenamehere.file and tries to find shortcuts in there (as far as I understand)

Comment: It's not possible that the code you posted would do that. Is `briefs.lnk` actually a shortcut? Are all parent folders of the shortcut regular directories (no symlinks/junctions)?

Comment: yes, it's just as I listed: F:\Connect\CLIENTA\briefs.lnk  <-- briefs.lnk "target" is \\IPADDRESS\CLIENTA\briefs\folder.  <-- I just need the 'target' of the link, which is \\IPADDRESS\ClientData\CLIENTA\briefs

Comment: Is there different code that would work for what i'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a command that will work in command prompt, but never seemed to work with powershell:

DIR /AL /S F:\Connect

It took a while to run... but it did.

Also, I found a program that did it in like 2 seconds:
http://sumtips.com/2012/10/find-symbolic-links-ntfs-junction-points-windows.html

I was trying to find the 'symbolic links' ... which I was stating targets.

Comment: `dir` is a CMD builtin command. To use it from PowerShell you need to run it in CMD (`& cmd /c dir /al /s F:Connect`). Also, shortcuts (.lnk files) are not junctions/symlinks and vice versa, so what is it that you actually have there?

Comment: I have a symlink. I assumed it worked like a shortcut. I guess I was wrong

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce. All the targets are probably found.

The results shown in the console by the `$output`-line should show everything as it should be. If not, update the question with the actual output, the desired output.

The only error I see here is that you try to save CSV-objects using output (text) redirection. That would only return the string-representation of the objects, which is not CSV. In this situation it doesn't output anything when I try it because `$output` is an array of objects that return nothing when the `ToString()` method is called.

Replace:

```
ECHO "$Output" >> $varCSVFile
```

With:

```
$Output | Select ShortcutName, ShortcutFull, ShortcutPath, Target | Export-CSV -Path $varCSVFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Sample output:

```
"ShortcutName","ShortcutFull","ShortcutPath","Target"
"WinSystem.lnk","C:\Users\frode\Desktop\test\WinSystem.lnk","C:\Users\frode\Desktop\test","C:\Windows\System"
"Lol.lnk","C:\Users\frode\Desktop\Lol.lnk","C:\Users\frode\Desktop","C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"
"Windows.lnk","C:\Users\frode\Desktop\Windows.lnk","C:\Users\frode\Desktop","\\localhost\c$\Windows"
"WinSystem32.lnk","C:\Users\frode\Desktop\WinSystem32.lnk","C:\Users\frode\Desktop","\\127.0.0.1\c$\Windows\System32"
```

**UPDATE** If you want it do a recursive search you could try something like this. Be aware that the target of the "second-level" shortcut (ex `\\server\share\shortcutb.nk` might have `c:\temp` as a target which means you'll get a local path and not an UNC for the remote computer (see `MyEnd.lnk` in sample output below).

**Warning**: This could easily result in a infinite loop (circular referencing) or long running search (because of recursive search).

```
 function Get-StartMenuShortcuts ($path) {
  $Shortcuts = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Include *.lnk
    #$Shortcuts = Get-ChildItem -Recurse "D:\Scripts\scott_testing" -Include *.lnk
    $Shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    foreach ($Shortcut in $Shortcuts)
    {
        $Properties = @{
            ShortcutName = $Shortcut.Name;
            ShortcutFull = $Shortcut.FullName;
            ShortcutPath = $shortcut.DirectoryName
            Target = $Shell.CreateShortcut($Shortcut).targetpath
        }

        Get-StartMenuShortcuts -path $Properties.Target

        New-Object PSObject -Property $Properties
    }

[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Shell) | Out-Null

}

$output = Get-StartMenuShortcuts -path "F:\Connect"
```

Example output:

```
"ShortcutName","ShortcutFull","ShortcutPath","Target"
"WinSystem.lnk","C:\Users\frode\desktop\test\WinSystem.lnk","C:\Users\frode\desktop\test","C:\Windows\System"
"MyEnd.lnk","\\127.0.0.1\c$\EFI\MyEnd.lnk","\\127.0.0.1\c$\EFI","C:\Users\frode\Desktop\TheEnd"
"EFI.lnk","C:\Users\frode\desktop\EFI.lnk","C:\Users\frode\desktop","\\127.0.0.1\c$\EFI"
"Lol.lnk","C:\Users\frode\desktop\Lol.lnk","C:\Users\frode\desktop","C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"
```

If you want to only get the deepest level, you should add a "level"-counter to each object that increases for each recursion call and then keep only the highest ones etc. It might get complicated depending on you needs so that would require a separate detailed question.

Comment: I re-read my initial post and I have re-worded it. I am trying to get the target of the shortcuts (shortcuts are links to other servers)

I tried your output and I can't even get that far.

Comment: It's still unclear and I still need the output and desired output.. You can't have shortcuts targeting a shortcut, and your solution (+ the `export-csv` part) returned the output above for me. It didn't look for `*.lnk` files inside `C:\Windows` etc. if that's what your saying

Comment: I need the target inside of a link. Ie: F:/folder/clienta/briefs.lnk. Inside of this link is a 'target' with ip address and folder. I need to record that information inside of a file. I need the output to say: \\IPADDRESS\clientdata\clientname . - as this is what the 'target' shows inside of the shortcut tab in the properties of the link. Now, there around around 100 folders inside of F:/connect/ that it needs to go through

Comment: It works fine for links using UNC-paths as well.. See updated ouptut in answer. I really don't understand what's wrong with your current solution.... Are you saying you want to find links recursively? Ex. `c:\shortcutA.lnk`  -> `\\server1\share` and `\\server1\share\shortcutB.lnk` -> `\\client1\c$\clientdata` ?

Comment: everything listed will work, but i am mostly wanting the last output that you listed:
\\client1\c$\clientdata  (assuming this is what is in your Shortcut tab in the 'Target' 

code for both sets, or 1 set will work.

Comment: Well there's no way (and by that I mean too much logic) to know which folder is the "deepest" one so we know which shortcuts to include... See updated for recursion sample

Comment: I tested your updated code and it still went inside of the target instead of listing the target.

There's not too much depth with this code set, but I would like to use it for other code sets:  

Ie: F:\program\client\folder\folder\briefs.lnk as well

Comment: What? :S The solution lists the shortcut and target itself while it also searched for new links (with targets) inside those. Did you want it to only go two levels deep (only list it not "access" the shortcuts inside the first shortcut-target)? Seriously, I have no idea what your talking about. Update the question with pictures, output, desires output etc....  At this point it is unclear what you're asking for (vote for close)